# How to mix audio files in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio

I need to mix two or more audios in nodejs.
My input files are: audio1.mp3, audio2.mp3, audio4.mp3.

I want them to be mixed like this:
on 0:00 seconds : audio1.mp3 should be added on the final mixed audio
on 0:30 seconds : audoio2.mp3 should be added on the final audio
on 00:35 : audio3.mp3 should be added on final audio

If audio1.mp3's length is of more than 30 seconds , then both audio1.mp3 and audio2.mp3 should play at same time.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can try using [web-audio-api](https://github.com/audiojs/web-audio-api)

Comment: Improved for legibility and clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used `sox` to mix them.
Example:

```
sox -m |sox audio1.mp3 -p pad 0:00 | sox audio2.mp3 -p 0:35 mixed.mp3
```